# Can't implement onsen through other file (app.js)

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

i'm making a sample app to learn how to use cordova, phonegap, angular.js and onsen ui. a nice tutorial video from CodeSchool about angular.js and this sample app (https://github.com/andipavllo/Google-Maps-Onsen-UI-Sample) show that we can implement onsen into our app by putting `var app = angular.module ('app',['onsen]);` in another file.

i've tried but it doesn't work. **it's working only when i put the `var app = angular.module ('app',['onsen']);` in the html file.**

i'm using onsen ui files from its official page. i've put those files where it was supposed to be(lib/onsen) and the app.js in the lib/onsen/js.

here is my code :

***Index.html***

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="id" ng-app = "apk">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

  <title>Sample App</title>  

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/onsen-css-components-blue-basic-theme.css">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css"/> 

  <script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>    
  <script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/onsen/js/app.js"></script> 

</head>

<body>

<ons-split-view 
    var="splitView"
    secondary-page="secondary.html" 
    main-page="main.html" 
    main-page-width="60%" >
  </ons-split-view>

  <ons-template id="secondary.html">
    <ons-page style="border-right: 1px solid #ddd;text-align:center; vertical-align:middle">
        <ons-toolbar style="background-color: #ffff99;"></ons-toolbar>
        <table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center">Welcome, please choose your language</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>

  <ons-template id="main.html" ng-controller="ApkController as apkctrl">
    <ons-page >
        <ons-toolbar style="background-color: #ffff99;">
            <div class="left">Choose Language</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
            <table style="width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">
                <tr>
                    <td><ons-button ng-click="apkctrl.pilbhs = 1" >Bahasa</ons-button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><ons-button ng-click="apkctrl.pilbhs = 2" >English</ons-button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>isi apkctrl.pilbhs : {{apk.pilbhs}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>
```

***app.js***

```
var app = angular.module('apk', ['onsen']);
ons.bootstrap().controller('ApkController', function ($scope) {

            this.pilbhs = indo;
    });

    var indo = 0;
```

instead of showing the app like here : http://codepen.io/fadynoor/pen/XbrzeB, the above code only show the hypertexted text/like no css in it (sorry, it's hard for me to describe it and stackoverflow prohibit me to post image)

***Correction***

i've just figured that the problem wasn't caused by the var app code. it was caused by an array-in-array variable i added in app.js.

my array-in-array code was like this :

```
var assawrah = [
    {
       number : '78',
       name : 'An-Naba',            
    },
    {
        number : '79',
        name : 'An-Naaziaat',
    },
    {
        number : '80',
        name : 'Abasa',
    },
    {
        number : '81',
        name : 'At-Takwir',
    },
    {
        number : '82',
        name : 'Al-Infithar',
        konten : [
            {
                latinINA : [{

                    }],
                latinEN : [{

                    }],
                terjemahanINA : [{

                    }],
                terjemahanEN : [{

                    }];
            }];
    }];
```

Comment: it should be `var app = angular.module ('app',['onsen']);` missing `'` at end

Comment: `app.js` is not supposed to be in  lib/onsen/js. That file is part of your app, not part of Onsen UI, so better put it outside lib folder. And well, you need to include `app.js` in your HTML (like Andi says below), otherwise that code won't be reached.

Comment: @FranDios : sorry, i've just realized that in this question i haven't included the var app code. i've edited my question. but i still have the same problem even after putting the app.js into a custom folder (scripts/app.js) which is put in the same folder with index.html and, of course including the `<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>` in index.html

Comment: @fady.noor does you issue has fixed?

Comment: sorry, the problem is something else. you can see the correction part of my question. sorry for the inconvinience and thanks very much for your help and suggestion :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw that you are using my sample app, so I guess I can help you about this. You have declared `ng-app="apk"`, so your js file should be something like:

```js
var app = angular.module('apk', ['onsen']);
    
    app.controller('MyController', function($scope){
      
        //Controller code
});
```

Remember to include your js file in the `index.html` file

```
<script src="/js/myScript.js"></script>
```

I suggest you to don't put your own script in the lib folder but create a custom folder.

Comment: i've done your suggestion, but i still have the same problem. check out my comment to FranDios above.